# Android RSS Feed parsing and running app as service

Tags: android, rss

I am making an app for my college where we have to parse RSS feed and display it. I am using SAX Parser to parse it and its working smoothly. Now I want two functionality in my app. First of all I want to run it as a service so that it may notify users about new events i.e new updates from RSS and how should I differentiate between the old RSS feed parsed and the new one so that I can show only the new updates.

Please give a overview on how can I implement these two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first question (how to make it a service) but I've done the second in a past life. The way I went about it was:

1. Compute the hash (sha1) from the title (you might want add other fields too)
2. Store the hash into a database along with time stamp
3. If the hash matches the entry in the database don't add it
4. if (3) fails add to database
5. Display everything in the database in descending order of timestamp (latest first)

Comment: I was also thinking adding to the database. But adding after hashing is new. Will try it for sure

Comment: a hash (sha1) is exactly 20 bytes in length. So you save a lot of space.

Comment: I am hosting my xml file on my webserver. Is there any place where I can host it so that I can update it every few hours? Logging into the webserver every now and then is not possible.

Comment: You mean the feed xml? Generally these are generated automatically by some kind of cms. Wordpress is one example. When there are new posts, the feed xml is automatically updated. I don't know how to do this manually. When I had to do this, I was to read feeds which were generated by a particular web site. I don't know how it was generated.